# How to integrate angular material in jhispter 7.6.0 monolothique application

Tags: angular, jhipster

Hi everyone a have a application using jhipster 7.6.0 and i want to install angular material.

This is the error I get when I run `ng add @angular/material`

[image]

I can not install material design problem on the screen capture below

[image]

I think I have the same error with the angular material installation

Comment: You should fix your npm environment as explained in your error `sudo chown ...` , there should not be any reason why your npm cache belongs to root user (even worse it's a security issue), they should belong to salif user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Material Design
for Bootstrap 5 & Angular 13](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b5/angular/). Here's how:

1. Install The MDB Angular UI KIT: `npm i mdb-angular-ui-kit`
2. Add the following to import MDB stylesheet in `src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss`:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap');
@import "~mdb-angular-ui-kit/assets/scss/mdb.scss";
```

3. Add `https://fonts.googleapis.com` and `https://fonts.gstatic.com` to the `style-src` and `font-src` content security policy rules in `src/main/resources/config/application.yml`.

```yaml
jhipster:
  ...
  security:
    content-security-policy: "... style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; ... font-src 'self' data: https://fonts.gstatic.com"
```

4. Remove the following styles from `global.scss`:

```
/* Error highlight on input fields */
.ng-valid[required],
.ng-valid.required {
  border-left: 5px solid green;
}
.ng-invalid:not(form) {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}
```

5. Modify the `.dropdown-menu` rule to set the display to `none`.

```
.dropdown-menu {
  padding-left: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

Below is a screenshot taken after these changes.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I ran npm i mdb-angular-ui-kit, but I still have a problem

Comment: thank you for your contribution I started jhipster with your book

Comment: With version 7.9.4 it gives an error: npm i mdb-angular-ui-kit --> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree